# laravel routing issue with controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am trying to basic route to controller but this is not working and it says"

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /member/john was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache Server at www.something.com Port 80

here is the code in routes.php:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function()
{
    //This should return main index page of site
    return 'Hello Khalid';
});


Route::get('member/{name}', 'MemberController@printName');
```

and this is the controller:

```
<?php

class MemberController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        return 'Welcome Mr. John';
    }

    public function printName($name)
    {
        return "Welcome, " . $name;
    }
}

?>
```

Finally this is the URL am visiting:

http://www.domainName.com/member/john

Comment: Add `Route::get('/test', function () { return 'test'; });` to your routes.php and go to domain.tld/test if it doesn't work the routing isn't properly set up

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` activated?

Comment: that's all what it was. Post an answer and I will approve it. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` has to be activated to make routing work under apache.

Answer (score 0):

Add / to your route.

```
Route::get('/member/{name}', 'MemberController@printName');
```